# The name does not exist on the current context

Tags: c#

How to get and use the control name from the mainform? For example is, I am creating a method in which files will be listed on a ListView. And I plan to create this method in a utility class but I get an error "does not contain on the current context".

```
public class UtilityClass
{
        private void SearchHeaderFiles( )
        {
            foreach(FileInfo f1 in...)
            {       
        listView.Items.Add(f1.Name);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to rethink your *concept* a bit. Usually *utility* classes have to operate in very *generic* (if I can say so) way. Making a specific method which uses `ListView` is either: 1) an extension of existing object (make it a method of own component then) 2) a generic method what will work with any `ListView` (then provide a way for it to know where to get this `ListView`: as a constructor parameter or as a method parameter).

Answer (score 2):

```
var listView = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["listView"] As ListView;
if (listView != null)
    listView.Items.Add(f1.Name);
```

Comment: always check for null in listView, if no item in list it will throw error.

Comment: Note, despite this is a working, but a dirty solution (thus not recommended). Intellisense is *disabled* (whenever you change form or control/component name -> run-time error) and form has to be opened first (which means shown?), so you cannot do this inside the form constructor.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree with you 100% this is a quick and dirty solution. The alternative way I can think of is to have ListView subscribe to utility class event so that it updates itself?